# Why is this function so slow?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, mysql, performance

My client has a WP website, its a real estate site with the properties setup as custom post types. Below is my search query to filter the listings based on a search form, all fairly standard stuff.

These pages are taking near 10 seconds to load and i cannot determine why, i have had a plugin enabled in the past that showed the queries themselves as taking around 100ms to run.

The site is fast generally, until you do a search, then it slows to a crawl

Until recently i thought it was just wordpress, its known to be slow in general but i bought a theme recently thats wordpress based and is a real estate management theme, its absolutely lightning fast compared to my clients site.

Its on a dedicated server, high end Xeon and is fairly low traffic, i don't think its hardware related as that other theme is fast on the same server.

What can i do to speed this up or properly debug it?

Any insight would be incredibly helpful, thanks

```
function search_listings( $query ) {

//* if within admin, return
if ( is_admin() ) {
    return;
}
//* if not main query, return
else if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
    return;
}
else if ( $query->is_main_query() && (is_post_type_archive( 'sales_listings' ) || is_post_type_archive( 'long_term_rentals' ) || is_post_type_archive( 'listings' ))) {
    if( (isset($_GET['price-min']) && $_GET['price-max'] != '')         || 
        (isset($_GET['price-max']) && $_GET['price-max'] != '')         ||
        (isset($_GET['beach']) && $_GET['beach'] != '')                 ||
        (isset($_GET['beds-min']) && $_GET['beds-min'] != '')           ||
        (isset($_GET['baths-min']) && $_GET['baths-min'] != '')         ||
        (isset($_GET['keyword']) && $_GET['keyword'] != '')             ||
        (isset($_GET['property_type']) && $_GET['property_type'] != '') ||
        (isset($_GET['location']) && $_GET['location'] != '')           ||
        (isset($_GET['confidential']) && $_GET['confidential'] != '')   ||
        (isset($_GET['dock']) && $_GET['dock'] != '')) {

        if(isset($_GET['price-min']) && $_GET['price-min'] != '') {
            $min_price  = sanitize_text_field($_GET['price-min']);
            $search_array['price-min'] = array( 'key'       => 'price',
                                                'value_num' => intval($min_price),
                                                'type'      => 'numeric',
                                                'compare'   => '>='
                                            );
        }
        if(isset($_GET['price-max']) && $_GET['price-max'] != '') {
            $max_price  = sanitize_text_field($_GET['price-max']);
            $search_array['price-max'] = array( 'key'       => 'price',
                                                'value' => intval($max_price),
                                                'type'      => 'numeric',
                                                'compare'   => '<='
                                            );
        }
        if(isset($_GET['beds-min']) && $_GET['beds-min'] != '') {
            $beds_min   = sanitize_text_field($_GET['beds-min']);
            $search_array['beds-min'] = array(  'key'       => 'beds',
                                                'value'     => intval($beds_min),
                                                'type'      => 'numeric',
                                                'compare'   => '>='
                                            );
        }
        if(isset($_GET['baths-min']) && $_GET['baths-min'] != '') {
            $baths_min  = sanitize_text_field($_GET['baths-min']);
            $search_array['baths-min'] = array( 'key'       => 'baths',
                                                'value'     => intval($baths_min),
                                                'type'      => 'numeric',
                                                'compare'   => '>='
                                            );
        }
        if(isset($_GET['confidential']) && $_GET['confidential'] == 'yes') {
            $search_array['private_collection'] = array(    'key'       => 'private_collection',
                                                            'value'     => 1,
                                                            'type'      => 'numeric',
                                                            'compare'   => '='
                                            );
        }
        if(isset($_GET['dock']) && $_GET['dock'] == 'yes') {
            $search_array['private_collection'] = array(    'key'       => 'dock',
                                                            'value'     => 1,
                                                            'type'      => 'numeric',
                                                            'compare'   => '='
                                            );
        }
        $keyword        = (isset($_GET['keyword']) && $_GET['keyword'] != '') ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['keyword']): '';
        if($keyword != '') {
            $query->set('s',$keyword);
        }
        if(isset($_GET['property_type']) && $_GET['property_type'] != '') {
            /*$property_type_array = "";
            foreach($_GET['property_type'] AS $key => $value) {
                // echo $value;
                $property_type_array[] = sanitize_text_field($value);
            }*/
            $property_type_array = sanitize_text_field($_GET['property_type']);
            $search_array['property_type'] = array( 'key'       => 'property_type',
                                                    'value'     => $property_type_array,
                                                    'compare'   => 'IN'
                                            );
        }
        if(isset($_GET['location']) && $_GET['location'] != '') {
            /*foreach($_GET['location'] AS $key => $value) {
                // echo $value;
                $location_array[] = sanitize_text_field($value);
            }*/
            $location_array = sanitize_text_field($_GET['location']);
            $search_array['location'] = array(  'key'       => 'location',
                                                'value'     => $location_array,
                                                'compare'   => '='
                                            );
        }
        if(isset($_GET['beach']) && $_GET['beach'] != '') {

            $beach = sanitize_text_field($_GET['beach']);
            $search_array['beach'] = array( 'key'       => 'beach',
                                            'value'     => $beach,
                                            'compare'   => '='
                                            );
        }
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 30);
        if(is_post_type_archive( 'sales_listings' ))
        {
            $query->set('post_type', array('sales_listings'));
        }
        else if(is_post_type_archive('long_term_rentals' ))
        {
            $query->set('post_type'     , 'long_term_rentals');
        }
        else if(is_post_type_archive('listings' ))
        {
            // $query->set('post_type'  , array('sales_listings','long_term_rentals'));
            $query->set('post_type' , 'listings');
        }

        if(!empty($search_array)) {
            $query->set('meta_query'    , $search_array);   
        }
        $query->set('meta_key'      , 'price');
        $query->set('orderby'       , 'meta_value_num');
        $query->set('order'         , 'DESC');
    }   
    else {
        if(is_post_type_archive( 'sales_listings' ))
        {
            $query->set('post_type'     , 'sales_listings');
        }
        else if(is_post_type_archive('long_term_rentals' ))
        {
            $query->set('post_type'     , 'long_term_rentals');
        }
        else if(is_post_type_archive('listings' ))
        {
            $query->set('post_type'     , array('sales_listings','long_term_rentals'));
        }

        $query->set('posts_per_page', 30);
        $query->set('meta_key'      , 'price');
        $query->set('orderby'       , 'meta_value_num');
        // $query->set('post_type'      , 'sales_listings');
        $query->set('order'         , 'DESC');      


    } 
}
```

}

Comment: Meta queries are not very efficient, and you have a lot of them. You’re going to have trouble getting any better performance without changing the data structure. At the very least You’ll get much better performance if you reimplement many of them as taxonomies. beach, property type, confidential, and dock all strike me as good candidates for taxonomies.

Comment: Yah i don't love the meta query element of things, and i agree they would hugely slow down things in any query however, if i search and do not add any GET queries, so this would just be loading the page with a minimum of joins i get 9.52 seconds for the time to first byte. Could there be some function hooked in a plugin slowing down this page time? Perhaps it will be best to download and disable things until its fast, ill do that now.

Comment: Please post one browser url that takes 10 seconds TTFB for analysis.  Copy to clipboard and paste in your Question, please.  And Slow Query Log for this query.

Comment: Paul, Just noticed within your function search_listings ~ 12th line price-min and price-max are mismatched.  Most variables are matched in this area.